# django admin add view Readonly Dropdown

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

```
class CaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'Status','Title','CaseCategory','Group']
    list_filter=['Status']
    date_hierarchy = 'CreatedDate'
    raw_id_fields = ('Customer',)
    fields= ['Customer', 'Title', 'Priority', 'Status', 'CaseCategory', 'Detail', 'Group', 'User']
```

here its my admin.py. The User field coming from Users table to the dropdownlist but this dropdown must be just readonly.

here its my screenshot [screenshot here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82QUu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need override `get_readonly_fields` method of BaseModelAdmin class

```
class CaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):    

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj:
          # For Update operation
          return self.readonly_fields + ('User',)
        # For Add operation
        return self.readonly_fields
```

Comment: if i do that 2 things User fields coming Empty or null and the "Add" operation occured error = "null value in column "User_id" violates not-null constraint"

Comment: Actually how can i give the default value this field ? I wanna give that authcanticated user.

Comment: Check my edit, Now for Update operation it is readonly and for Add it has no effect.

Comment: `how can i give the default value this field?` This is a separate question you need post it as a new question. if above answer helped please upvote and accept the answer.